# Have a specific nested UL element open upon page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pppL1rwx/2/)

I've created a very simple "archive tree" that uses nested ULs and LIs to browse through years, months and days. Currently, I have one problem that I'd like to solve:

If you click any of the day links that lead to another page, I'd like for the whole thing to stay open to that month. (For example, like having an "active" class for a navbar element, only in this case, the UL element would display as a block on the new page for that month, as if it had been opened previously. I have tried adding a separate class to display as a block, but it does not change (see JSFiddle).

```
.month-active {
    display: block;
}

<ul class="archive_year">
    <li class="year-button"><button class="navbutton">key5</button>
        <ul class="archive_month">
            <li class="month-button"><button class="navbuttoninner">key53</button>
                <ul class="archive_dayList month-active">
                    <li class="archive_day"><a href="#">Test link</a></li>
                    <li class="archive_day"><a href="#">Test link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `data` attribute to each link, then set a `localStorage` item with the value for the last link clicked. And on page load, if the `localStorage` item is set, show that element and traverse back up the DOM and show the parents, too.

Since this won't work in the sandbox on SO, here's a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/pppL1rwx/4/

```js
if (localStorage.lastClicked) {
  $('[data-id="' + localStorage.lastClicked + '"]').parentsUntil('.parent').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings().addBack().slideDown();
  });
}

$('.year-button, .month-button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  var clicked = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
  if (clicked) {
    localStorage.lastClicked = clicked;
  }
});
```

```css
.navbutton {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #cfa9db;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.navbuttoninner {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #cfa9db;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 290px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.archive_year {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
}

.archive_month {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.archive_dayList {
  margin-left: 32px;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.month-button {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.archive_day {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.archive_month,
.archive_dayList {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <ul class="archive_year">
    <li class="year-button">
      <button class="navbutton">2017</button>
      <ul class="archive_month">
        <li class="month-button">
          <button class="navbuttoninner">June</button>
          <ul class="archive_dayList">
            <li class="archive_day"><a href="#" data-id="link1">Test link</a></li>
            <li class="archive_day"><a href="#" data-id="link2">Test link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="archive_month">
        <li class="month-button">
          <button class="navbuttoninner">July</button>
          <ul class="archive_dayList">
            <li class="archive_day"><a href="#" data-id="link3">Test link</a></li>
            <li class="archive_day"><a href="#" data-id="link4">Test link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @ZsophiaNorris you're welcome :) btw, if this solved the problem, you should choose it as the solution. And you should choose an answer in your other question (that you asked last year), too, since it looks like you got what you were looking for there.

Comment: @ZsophiaNorris you click the little checkmark beside answers to choose the best solution to the problem.